# Windows 10 dual boot - Ubuntu/GRUB disappeared

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Acer Aspire F15. Windows 10 home edition (pah)
The more I use W 10 the more desperate I am to get Linux running on this PC.

Disabled fast startup as recommended.
Power button set to 'power down' not hibernate.

Installed latest Ubuntu (can't boot to it anymore to check version)

After initial installation the PC booted by default to Windows, so next boot I hit F12 and got the boot options/list.

Scrolled down to my ubuntu drive and selected it:

Result: booted to GRUB, which gave me the correct available options (Windows or Ubuntu)

Selected Ubuntu, and booted.

Excellent, Ubuntu, wireless network setup etc etc etc.

Shut down, thinking that all I'd need to do is hit F12 on next power up and change the boot order.

That's where things went wrong.

Now when I hit F12 all I get are the boot to Windows options.
No sign of Ubuntu anywhere on the F12 menu (only 2 options now, and neither of them is ubuntu)

The bit that has me really confused is that I did manage to get it to boot to Grub, once.

How do I get it to show Grub/Ubuntu again, so I can make the change permanent?

Problems with W 10 appear to be common enough, but I've not found anything similar in my searches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UEFI settings do not persist across reboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645791/uefi-settings-do-not-persist-across-reboot)

Comment: Don't think so, as the stated solution definitely does not work in this case. It would appear that the Anniversary update to W 10 is the culprit but I've yet to come across a working solution. It would appear that all of the linux distros are similarly impacted, so I guess a solution will be found, sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Im using windows 8.1 os, and i was able to use a windows compatible boot loader to show both options windows and ubuntu. Try easy BCD, the instructions are on the web, but let me know if you still need help.

Comment: No joy with easyBCD. It's not seeing my linux/grub partition either. Using the GUI ('cause I'm tired and not all that smart) all options other than windows are greyed out. Disk management says that my linux partition is healthy, but I can't apply a drive letter to it or do anything with it - it's definitely there, but nothing seems to be able to get to it.

Comment: can you describe all the steps you did and what guide you used here, i can tell you what step you missed.

Comment: Hi Steven, This is my second attempt at installing linux on this laptop. My first attempt was with Debian (as per my other two older PCs. On that attempt I was able to boot to Linux, only, and after several hours in consultation with my local PC guru between us we could only boot to Windows. Debian partition removed. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) followed, with one exception - W10 was pre-installed, there i no way I was going to remove it and re-install it later as per these instructions.

Comment: This time fast start disabled first before starting. UBUNTU USB key used  for installation. "Windows and" option selected. The installation was successful. On my first reboot the machine went straight to windows, so rebooted and hit F12 (boot manager). There were a few entries - at least 2 for windows and my linux install. I selected my linux install and everything was good. Shut down, rebooted, F12 again, with the intention of changing the boot order, only this time my only boot options were W10 - two entries for some reason. I checked again this morning and there is one entry now W10.

Comment: sorry i dual boot os all the time now and that never happened to me, what most people recommend is to install windows os first, then install linux with GRUB bootloader on top of it.

Comment: for some reason when you install windows on top of linux, window os overwrites the MBR of the linux partition and that will only allow you to boot to windows itself.

Answer (score 0):

Mount efi partition in microsoft boot rename bootmgfw.efi 
To bootmgfw_.efi and replace bootmgfw.efi with copy of grub2.efi and then edit grub.cfg to set windows bootloader name to bootmgfw_.efi

How to mount efi partition on windows 10

https://youtu.be/sR68Kr_Hapo

Comment: I  gave up on this in the end and passed the offending laptop on to my wife who is prepared to live with W10 only. I acquired a new to me laptop and made it linux only (Mint) and so have forsaken dual boot for the forseeable future.