# Cannot permanently remove boot entry using efibootmgr

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

My notebook is Lenovo G50-45. I have two dual boot systems Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I also had Phoenix OS with separate dual boot with Windows 10 (I suppose there is second Grub). I deleted unused system Phoenix via Gparted. Though I cannot delete the efi boot entry. Precisely, I can delete it, but it shows up again after reboot.
I used efibootmgr in Linux:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 6 -B
```

In Windows I tried EasyUefi, there it shows even after refresh I do not have to reboot.
I do not understand much what is happening by EFI booting. Can someone suggest solution? 
Here are my current settings:

```
honza@lenovoG50:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 15 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,2003,0005,0006,0000,2001,2002
Boot0000* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,GPT,b11a59bf-42d6-4548-b244-1858af8a20e4,0x276800,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0001* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (68-F7-28-92-3E-35)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(68f728923e35,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (68-F7-28-92-3E-35)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(68f728923e35,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,c3623e25-a72c-492b-8ff5-9ea449e37436,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,c3623e25-a72c-492b-8ff5-9ea449e37436,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(3,GPT,b11a59bf-42d6-4548-b244-1858af8a20e4,0x276800,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0006* Phoenix OS    HD(2,GPT,c3623e25-a72c-492b-8ff5-9ea449e37436,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\PhoenixOS\Boot\bootx64.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.1.e.a.a.d.8.9.3.-.d.e.d.e.-.1.1.e.7.-.b.f.a.7.-.b.5.e.0.8.c.6.0.2.4.d.f.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

**EDIT**

I followed advice and after reboot to Windows this is output of EasyUEFI:
[image: EasyUEFI list of boot entries.]

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu/1042032#1042032) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I incorrectly formatted Phoenix OS, it did not do any visible damage, and also did many other attempts and experiment. Surprisingly, I could boot all system I have (Windows 10, ubuntu 16.04).
Therefore

**1. If your plan is to uninstall Phoenix OS, find proper instructions**

(see e. g. my https://superuser.com/questions/1398508/difference-between-easyuefi-boot-item-and-mounted-disk-folder/1398626#1398626 
B. paragraph)

**2. Removing Phoenix system boot entry, if you incorrectly uninstalled Phoenix OS**

a) In ubuntu efibootmgr does not seem to do much. Only check what entries are there by:

```
 sudo efibootmgr -v
```

b) In Windows the easiest way comes from:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyOBF2ePvHY

using bcdedit in admin command prompt: to see all bootable options.

```
bcdedit /enum all
```

There are (usually) many items. So, if you see it for the first time you may get lost. I think the best is to compare it with EasyUEFI outup. See in picture in question:

```
File path:\EFI\PhoenixOS\Boot\bootx64.efi.
```

I show small part of my bcdedit /enum all output:

```
 Firmware Boot Manager
 ---------------------
 identifier              {fwbootmgr}
 displayorder            {1eaad893-dede-11e7-bfa7-b5e08c6024df}
                         {933ae2d3-bf4b-11e4-8258-68f728923e35}
                         {19f0e09b-20f3-11e9-83f9-806e6f6e6963}
                         {c2d01e39-20bc-11e9-83f6-806e6f6e6963}
                         {203b70a1-1fd2-11e9-83f3-806e6f6e6963}
                         {881ea240-bf4f-11e4-8a37-806e6f6e6963}
                         {881ea242-bf4f-11e4-8a37-806e6f6e6963}
                         {881ea23e-bf4f-11e4-8a37-806e6f6e6963}
                         {164f529a-6ec2-11e7-8308-806e6f6e6963}
 timeout                 6

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {1eaad893-dede-11e7-bfa7-b5e08c6024df}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\PhoenixOS\Boot\bootx64.efi
description             Phoenix OS
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
resumeobject            {933ae2da-bf4b-11e4-8258-68f728923e35}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 0
```

I did not care about "Windows Boot Manager" important is path for identification. Next you have to copy UUID (=identifier item) {1eaad893-dede-11e7-bfa7-b5e08c6024df}. (It should vary in your case). And delete this entry by:

```
bcdedit /delete {1eaad893-dede-11e7-bfa7-b5e08c6024df}
```

I did reboot. But I think it is not necessary. Now, you should not see Phoenix OS boot entry either in EasyUEFI nor by `bcdedit /enum all` nor in BIOS boot options. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

When logged into the installed Ubuntu, type the following command, as root, to delete a specific entry:

```
efibootmgr -b 0006 -B
```

The number (0006) is the hexadecimal number representing the entry you want to delete.

and type in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Vijay: It removed entry in linux. I did not see it in BIOS, after I booted to Windows and started EasyUEFI it was here. Could be there some backup process?

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I re-do the process, when Phoenix appears in Ubuntu: 
honza@lenovoG50:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-140-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-140-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-130-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-130-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

Comment: If not solved [try from Windows](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/)  If still not solved it is a firmware problem. See this [also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645791/uefi-settings-do-not-persist-across-reboot/645914#645914)

Comment: It seems that [try from Windows](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/) with proper options worked. So delete phoenix EFI folder seems to be a solution.

Comment: After a few reboots Phoenix is back again.

Answer (score 0):

'Grub Customizer' worked easily for me. I'm running ver. 5.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

After using Boot repair I had multiple Win10 listings in boot two booted correctly into windows two did not. Grub Customizer easily fixed that. You can revert back also.

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If possible you should explain in your answer the steps needed instead of linking to remote sources, since they are likely to change or go offline in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for others who may find this issue:  I have the same problem where I can remove the last entry (an entry for a partition that no longer exists) either with `efibootmgr -b nnnn -B` or `bcdedit /delete {guid}` and they both show the entry successfully removed by either `efibootmgr -v` or `bcdedit /enum all`.  However, upon next reboot that entry still appears in the list presented by the UEFI BIOS.  I have not found a way to remove it.  I even set it to `disabled` in the BIOS but it still appears in the BIOS boot menu.  Maybe be a firmware issue?

I also tried changing the boot order `sudo efibootmgr -o 0002,0000` thinking that with the bogus entry (0003) in the boot order might be locking it or something.  But a reboot after changing the order brought up the AMI fTPM message -- apparently noticing I'd changed the boot order.  I took the "Y" option to reset the fTMP but when I went back to check the boot order was back to the original.  So, nothing I've tried will remove, disable, or otherwise hide that entry.

Does it have anything to do with there is no longer a 0001 entry listed?

But, this bogus entry doesn't appear in the Grub menu (since that partition doesn't exist anymore) so,for now, I guess I live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I initially experienced the same problem as you, but my problem was resolved after trying to run `sudo efibootmgr` then I deleted the unused OS directory at `/boot/efi/EFI` I hope my solution can solve your problem.