# Issues with my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I like running Windows on my laptop because I don't do a lot on it and Windows keeps things simple since Windows is the world.

But now I'm wanting to do some development sometimes and I want my Ubuntu dev environment. So I struck on the bright idea to get an external hard drive and load ubuntu on that. Then I can make the USB drive first in the boot order and when I boot, it will boot into Ubuntu.

Then, I unplug the drive and it boots Windows. In theory this sounds great.

My Ubuntu drive is working like a charm, so I unplug it to test Windows boot and it comes up at the grub boot loader in some kind of command state, probably in error.

All the ones I've found on here are for much older versions of Ubuntu. I'm on 20.10.

I tried using Windows bootrec to fix the master boot record, but it just says "Path not Specified."

I have no idea how to fix this, so I'm asking the gurus.

Comment: *Grub boot loader in some kind of command state, probably in error* -- What is the error? Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1334203/edit) the question. Also, what exactly did you try? You used Windows bootrec, is your Windows also not booting? You said Ubuntu was working for you, it is not clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: *Windows keeps things simple since Windows is the world* --  

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi You understand that I'm not happy about this, just accepting reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other links inlcuding [How to restore Windows boot loader after removing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240994/how-to-restore-windows-boot-loader-after-removing-ubuntu), but this did not help me.

What ended up doing it was I was looking at the UEFI boot order and I realized one of them was Windows. So I tried that one. DUH! Fixed it. Boots windows now, but booting to linux is a distant dream. I'll have to to UEFI boot every time I want to go there.

Alas!