Can I fully reset my laptop to delete Grub/Ubuntu?
Before I get into it, I must stress I am complete beginner at this and wish I never tried to dual boot, caused nothing but stress. HP Omen 16l Laptop. Windows 11.
Issue is when I turn my laptop on it opens straight up on the Grub screen. I have to press f9 to get onto the boot options and get into windows that way, which don't always work. I also can't update/install GPU drivers because I get an error stating that there is an OS error (AMD error 192).
I've tried to check the partitions to see if they were different but I only have the one partition with windows on (I downloaded Ubuntu on flash drive).
I'm wondering if I can just fully reset my laptop clean and get rid of Ubuntu/Grub? Will that stop it booting straight into grub and will it fix being able to install new drivers? Not bothered about a clean slate, there's only games on there anyway.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240994/how-to-restore-windows-boot-loader-after-removing-ubuntu

Ubuntu is an OS, Grub is a bootloader is is used by many OSes including Ubuntu.  The bootloader allows you to select which OS to boot from, and other options; but you can use your windows recovery media and/or the windows command that will cause a windows bootloader to be used instead (doing this may prevent Ubuntu from being booted; but if you're removing Ubuntu that won't be a problem)

This question is similar to: How to delete GRUB entirely from GRUB rescue and boot Windows only. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
